# Netlify not displaying my website as it should / not seeing the packages used in node_modules folder

Tags: npm, package, node-modules, netlify

I built a website using npm and in it I used swiperJS installed through npm. It works fine on local development environment but when I deployed to netlify, it does not display as it should where I used the package. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a repo or any more information with your build configurations?

Comment: I don't have a build configuration, I used instructions given by Tailwindcss link 
>>  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: We don't know anything about your code without seeing it, folks can't just spin up a new environment to help out! Please share more if you would like a better answer.

Comment: https://github.com/CyberDevv/Decbase/tree/9998312fb0efd1e45dce5180c3c71fa2f8641ec1 that is the link to the repositiory, thank you